# Count sum of records where value = 1

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to count all the records from multiple tables that have `attr3` as a value of 1.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT 'Dept' AS table_name, COUNT(*)
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.attr3='1' AND table2.attr3='1'
```

The problem I am having is that it's showing the wrong number. It should display as `7`, but instead it's `12`.

I have to write it in such a way because `attr3` is a foreign key so some solutions may come up with `attr3 is ambiguous`

Anyone know where I may be going wrong? Thank you

**EDIT**

I then want to apply the same query two more times but with different values to get separate counts:

```
SELECT 'Dept' AS table_name, COUNT(*)
FROM table1, table2
WHERE table1.attr3='2' AND table2.attr3='2'
```

Minimizing code would be a big plus!

Comment: give us a sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comma operator creates a Cartesian product.  That produces way more rows than you want (under most circumstances).  Instead, use `union all` along with your condition:

```
SELECT 'Dept' AS table_name, COUNT(*)
FROM ((select attr3 from table1) union all
      (select attr3 from table2)
     ) t
WHERE attr3 = '1';
```

Comment: thanks very much. Quick question, what's the use of `t`? Why does it need to be there?

Comment: @Paji.R . . . MySQL requires a table alias for a subquery in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: ah yes that makes sense now :) If I wanted to do this statement twice, but have the `WHERE` clause pick out a different value, how would I use a join using your solution to display the separate results in their relative tables?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UNION`, not `JOIN`, to combine the two tables, since you're not relating rows to each other between the tables. Then use `GROUP BY` to get the counts for each `attr3`.

```
SELECT attr3, COUNT(*) 
FROM (
    SELECT attr3 FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT attr3 FROM table2
) AS u
GROUP BY attr3
```

It might be better to do the counts in each table separately, then sum them. If you have an index on `attr3`, this will be able to take advantage of it.

```
SELECT attr3, SUM(count)
FROM (
    SELECT attr3, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY attr3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT attr3, COUNT(*)
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY attr3
) AS u
GROUP BY attr3
```

Make sure you use `UNION ALL`, not just `UNION`, since by default it will remove duplicates.

Comment: this solution has gave me the following result. http://puu.sh/sR5k4/2758a6d06a.png

Comment: It should show as `3` then `4` and I want there to only be two entries?

Comment: If you only want the counts for 3 and 4, add `WHERE attr3 IN (3, 4)` to the queries.